# Micronaut get handling object/method in Filter

Tags: java, annotations, micronaut

So i have following controller

```
Controller("/test")
public class MyController {
    @Get("/anno")
    @MyAnnotation(value="my annotation value") // <---- i want this value
    public Object testAnnotation(HttpRequest<?> request){
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement custom filter on micronauts http server.

```
@Filter("/**")
public class MyFilter implements HttpServerFilter {
    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {


        // HERE
        // how to get the MyAnnotation value from the handling method for the request ?

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

How to get my custom annotation inside the filter ?
Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Spring AOP.

Comment: Or you can use a custom Header and get it from the request in your filter.

Comment: "I suggest you take a look at Spring AOP." - Using Spring AOP in a Micronaut app for this is going to require that controller be configured as a Spring bean, which doesn't make any sense in the context of a Micronaut app.

Answer (score 0):

You would need AOP, Micronauts supports it. But you get it from a `MethodInterceptor`, not `HttpFilter`. Here is the code I modified based on what I wrote for tracing, in Kotlin, it would be very similar in Java:

```
@Singleton
@InterceptorBean(MyAnnotation::class)
class MyAnnotationInterceptor : MethodInterceptor<Any, Any> {


    override fun intercept(context: MethodInvocationContext<Any, Any>): Any? {
        val myAnnotation: AnnotationValue<MyAnnotation> = context.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation::class.java)!!
        val value = myAnnotation.get("value", String::class.java).orElse(null)
        val className = context.declaringType.simpleName
        val methodName = context.methodName
        val operationName = "$className.$methodName"
        val interceptedMethod = InterceptedMethod.of(context)

        try {
            when (interceptedMethod.resultType()) {
                SYNCHRONOUS -> {
                    try {
                        return context.proceed()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        throw e
                    } finally {
                    }
                }
                COMPLETION_STAGE -> {
                    try {
                        var completionStage = interceptedMethod.interceptResultAsCompletionStage()
                        return interceptedMethod.handleResult(completionStage)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        logError(newSpan, e)
                        throw e
                    }
                }
                else -> return interceptedMethod.unsupported()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return interceptedMethod.handleException<RuntimeException>(e)
        }
    }
}
```

`val value = myAnnotation.get("value", String::class.java).orElse(null)` is where you get the value.

We use the above code to extract the tracing sampling rate and it works well for us. Note that your annotation will need "around" AOP annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(CLASS, FILE, FUNCTION, PROPERTY_GETTER, PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Around
annotation class MyAnnotation(
    val value: String = "", 
)
```